# URL Link in second li using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add url in ul second li. But getting error. I tried this below jquery code

```
$('.breadcrumb ol li:nth-child(2)').append('<a href="\search.php?' + $(this).html() + '" />');
});
```

HTML code

```
<ol>
<li class="breadcrumb">abc</li>
<li class="breadcrumb">abc</li>
<li  class="breadcrumb">abc</li>
<li  class="breadcrumb">abc</li>
</ol>
```

I am not good in Js. Just need help. Thanks

Comment: $('ol .breadcrumb li:nth-child(2)') and what is the error that you are getting?

Comment: '<a href="/search.php?' + $(this).html() + '" />'

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong jQuery selector and not closing `<a>` tag.

Jquery Selectors work like CSS, you need to follow the order of the written HTML, so if you have an `<ol>` and inside an `<li>` tag you need to write like this to select the right ones:

`$('ol li.breadcrumb')`

Use the following for your case, `.wrap()` is used to wrap the content with a tag that you pass to it:

```js
$('ol li.breadcrumb:nth-child(2)').wrap('<a href="#" />');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol>
  <li class="breadcrumb">abc</li>
  <li class="breadcrumb">abc</li>
  <li  class="breadcrumb">abc</li>
  <li  class="breadcrumb">abc</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: I don't want to add Test, Just add a link in second li 'abc'

Comment: Edited the answer!! :)

Answer (score 0):

There is wrong JQuery selector is injected, Just use

`$('ol li.breadcrumb:nth-child(2)').wrap('<a href="/search.php?' + $(this).html() + '" />');`

and That should be forward slash in your search URL.

Comment: Can you clear, why were you adding `$(this).html()` in the `/search.php` parameter?

Comment: Or do you like to search for that text of that `li`?